# Need notification if Android closes Service

Tags: android, service

In several apps we use local services to (for example) record locations. This is working perfect for some time (e.g. 4 hours or 150km) and then Android closes (no longer wants) the service. The service is not crashing it's Android that decides to close the service.

It's written in the docs and it's ok BUT I need to find out that a service has been closed. How can I do that?

I would like to restart our service as soon as possible. How do you guys find out that a service has been closed by Android? Do you use finalize?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would like to know why I received a downvote without an explanation. Bad style.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to return `Service.START_STICKY` or `Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from `Service.onStartCommand()` method?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use Service.START_STICKY always.

Comment: Isn't you service restarted after it's destroyed by Android?

Comment: No, definetely. The docs say Android would try to restart but there's no guarantee neither. So no onDestroy guarantee and no restart guarantee. Would really like to know how you guys work around this.

Comment: As far as I understand docs say that returning `Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT` guarantees that the service will be rescheduled after termination. I'm not sure it works in this way really.

Answer (score 0):

Your service's onDestroy method should be called as it is destroyed by Android OS.  Also you should see in logs that normally android re-boots your service after a short time period, which is shown in the logs as it is destroyed, in my experience its around 15-30 seconds before it is booted again. (Every service you have in your app will be booted in a random order so beware if some services rely on other services in your app.)

Comment: Hmm, my services are never restarted. And onDestroy is never called. I know that for sure because all items like Icon in NotificationBar and a lot more are removed in onDestroy and whenever Android decides to "no longer want" my service these items are still active - and the service is gone. I read somewhere that there's no guaratee that you'll receive onDestroy on service termination.